# Any ideas for a photo booth props at a market?

Tags: business, photo-booth

I am putting together a farmers' market/flea market photo booth. I was hoping someone could give me some ideas for props that are cheap and easy. This is just a trial I am running locally.

Comment: Your farmers' markets are obviously very different to the ones I've been to...

Answer (score 3):

Nothing specific, but this time of year (at least in this area) there are a lot of rummage sales... you can make out really good with those for things in the $.25-$1.00 range. Check your local newspaper or Craiglist for ones in your area.

Another spot that I have had success with is thrift stores.. specifically..

Goodwill:

- Costumes
- Vintage or other clothing (to wear or even to make into backgrounds)
- General Odds and Ends

ReStore (Run by Habitat for Humanity):

- Interesting Mirrors and Light Fixtures
- Frames / Wood pieces for backgrounds

Again you are likely to find things that will work great that you might not have thought about before seeing them catch your eye.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Go for something novel, locally to me there's a couple who run a 'moon booth' which is essentially a photo booth that lets you look like you're sitting on the moon. People adore it because it's a novel concept.

You don't necessarily need lots of props, just a good idea for one. Go have a rummage around charity/clearance stores and I'm sure you'll stop and spot something that ticks the creative box in your brain.